# Is there a way to place a pin into the google maps iphone app using openURL?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I would like to create an iPhone app that can open the google maps app and place a pin on the map.

I have the exact location of the pin, specified by its longitude and latitude.
I also have a name for the pin e.g. 'location 1' that should be displayed along with the pin.

I know that UIApplication:openURL can be used for this but I don't know the exact url format.

So, is there a way to do what I described above? If, yes, what is the correct url format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a URL of the format: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Your+Location+name@latitude,longitude

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=This+is+near+Lake+Shore+Drive@41.9288,-87.6315

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems that the second link you provide is not working. It is actually the same as the first one.

Comment: There was a space in the URL. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop up to 100 pins using KML. There is an example of this on http://appsamuck.com look at the example for day 8 (http://appsamuck.com/day8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why should your user have to exit your app to see a map.  You can embed a Google map in your application easily.  You can even drop multiple pins for which you have lat & long information.

In fact, in my opinion your user should never have to leave your application to view a google map.

An example of how to do this is included as an example application at https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickconnect/.

Download the QuickConnectiPhone zip file and you will find it in the Examples directory.

Comment: Due to license restrictions, you can’t use Turn-Based directions in your own MKMapView if you use Google’s map tiles.