# Is it possible to drop a pin and create routing path on the iOS Google Map app using url scheme

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am doing a App which allows user to tap a location then redirects user to the Google Map App and show the routing path. Is it possible to drop a pin and create routing path on the iOS Google Map app using url scheme since I don't want to use the google map sdk inside app. If it is possible, can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Just find a good answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218252/is-there-a-way-to-place-a-pin-into-the-google-maps-iphone-app-using-openurl

Answer (score 0):

Yes, form google [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
} else {
  NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

To drop a pin on the map use `comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135`
This is also from [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

Comment: It cannot drop a pin on the map.